# print uint32_t to string in C but not it's literally value

Tags: c, string, printing, hex, uint32-t

I'm reading an image file and I want to show the format it was compressed in console.

In example, I read this: `format = 861165636 (0x33545844)`, as my CPU reads and writes in Little Endian I do `format = __builtin_bswap32(format);` so now `format = 1146639411 (0x44585433)`, and `0x44585433 = "DXT3"` in ASCII.

I want to print this ("DXT3") but not using and extra variable, I mean, something like this `printf("Format: %s\n", format);` (that obviously crash). There's a way to do it?

Comment: So you want to interpret a uint32_t buffer as if it were a four byte array of ASCII characters?

Comment: @jwdonahue you literally summarized all the question in 1 sentence :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` paratameter indicates if you want to start from the most significant byte or not.

```
void printAsChars(uint32_t val, int order)
{   
    if(!order)
    {
        putchar((val >> 0) & 0xff);
        putchar((val >> 8) & 0xff);
        putchar((val >> 16) & 0xff);
        putchar((val >> 24) & 0xff);
    }
    else
    {
        putchar((val >> 24) & 0xff);
        putchar((val >> 16) & 0xff);
        putchar((val >> 8) & 0xff);
        putchar((val >> 0) & 0xff);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printAsChars(0x44585433,0); putchar('\n');
    printAsChars(0x44585433,1); putchar('\n');
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WWE9Yr

Another option

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uint32_t val = 0x44585433;
    printf("%.4s", (char *)&val);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eEj755

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why the order parameter is needed? The OP probably hasn't considered little/big endianess.

Comment: I loved the simplicity of the second option, and thanks for that website too, It goes directly to my bookmarks.

Answer (score -3):

`printf("Format: %c%c%c%c\n", format << 24, format << 16, format << 8, format & 256);` 
or something like that. untested. Maybe you need to mask the chars.

Comment: Your code will not work. It is a good habit **to test the code before** answering the question. If you do not test - simply do not answer